# Proof of the commutator $[A,f(B)]=[A,B]\frac{\partial f(B)}{\partial B}$ of a function $f$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I didn't find any post where this demonstration was given, and also there is no much information on internet, so I will upload my demonstration in the answers.

We want to proof that with the conditions,

- $f(B)$ an analytical function $\Leftrightarrow$ expressable in a $B$ power series
- The operators fulfill $[[A,B],B]=0$

The following expression can be used,

$$[A,f(B)]=[A,B]\frac{\partial f(B)}{\partial B}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can express the function in power series $$f(B)=\sum c_n B^n$$And we can see the derivative will look as,
$$\frac{\partial f(B)}{\partial B}=\frac{\partial}{\partial B}\sum c_n B^n=\sum c_n\frac{\partial B^n}{\partial B}=\sum c_n n B^{n-1}$$

And we are ready to start with the proof,

\begin{align*}[A,f(B)]=\sum c_n[A,B^n]&=\sum c_n (B^{n-1}[A,B]+[A,B^{n-1}]B)\\
&=\sum c_n (B^{n-1}[A,B]+B^{n-2}[A,B]B+[A,B^{n-2}]B^2)
\end{align*}
Here is where we use the commutation $[[A,B],B]=[[A,B],A]=0$ that allow us to redistribute the operators,

\begin{align*}&=\sum c_n (B^{n-1}[A,B]+B^{n-2}[A,B]B+[A,B^{n-2}]B^2) \\
&=\sum c_n (B^{n-1}[A,B]+B^{n-1}[A,B]+B^{n-1}[A,B]+[A,B^{n-3}]B^3) \\
& \cdots \\
&=\sum c_n n B^{n-1}[A,B]
\end{align*}

And as we seen we can identify the derivative,

$$[A,f(B)]=[A,B]\frac{\partial f(B)}{\partial B}$$

Comment: We can see that also a property derived is $[A,B^n]=nB^{n-1}[A,B]$